# Python 3.6 memcached

Tags: app-engine-flexible

Getting confused by the myriad of google python packages. Does anybody know which one I need for my python 3.6 application to use App Engine memcached back end for the flask-caching library?

Answer (score 1):

There is no memcached provided by App Engine flexible environment. You have to use an external memcache service, such as one from RedisLabs, or roll your own in a compute engine vm.